# Error al usar Nested resources "undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estoy tratando de hacer una relacion en la que un producto tiene un productospza, estoy siguiendo este tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a61yKxi3pL0 pero cuando en el formulario para crear un nuevo producto pueda a su vez crear un productosxpza añadiendo el campo en el formulario y coloco en el controlador:

```
def new
    @producto = Producto.new
    @producto.productosxpza.build
  end
```

me aparece el siguiente error: "undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass" al cargar el formulario de new. he estado buscando mi falla pero no la consigo.

el modelo de producto:

```
class Producto < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = "clave"

  has_one :productosxpza, class_name: "Productosxpza", foreign_key: "producto_id"

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :productosxpza

end
```

el de productosxpza:

```
class Productosxpza < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = "idp"

  belongs_to :producto, class_name:"Productosxpza"
end
```

el formulario de producto:

```
    <%= form_for(@producto) do |f| %>
  <% if @producto.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@producto.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this producto from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @producto.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

    <%= f.fields_for :productosxpza do |productosxpza| %>
    <div class="productosxpza_fields">
      <div class="field">
      <%= productosxpza.label :pzaxcja %><br>
      <%= productosxpza.number_field :pzaxcja %>
    </div>

    </div>
    <%end%>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :clave %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :clave %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :producto %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :producto %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

y el controlador de producto:

```
    class ProductosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_producto, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_usuario!

  # GET /productos
  # GET /productos.json
  def index
    @productos = Producto.all
    @producto = Producto.new

  end

  # GET /productos/1
  # GET /productos/1.json
  def show

  end

  # GET /productos/new
  def new
    @producto = Producto.new
    @producto.productosxpza.build
  end

  # GET /productos/1/edit
  def edit

  end

  # POST /productos
  # POST /productos.json
  def create
    @producto = Producto.new(producto_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @producto.save
        format.html { redirect_to @producto, notice: 'Producto was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @producto }
        format.js #ajax
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @producto.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js #ajax
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /productos/1
  # PATCH/PUT /productos/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @producto.update(producto_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @producto, notice: 'Producto was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @producto }
        format.js #ajax
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @producto.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js #ajax
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /productos/1
  # DELETE /productos/1.json
  def destroy
    @producto.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to productos_url, notice: 'Producto was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
      format.js #ajax
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_producto
      @producto = Producto.find(params[:id])
    end


    def producto_params
      params.require(:producto).permit(:clave, :producto, productosxpza_attributes: [:id, :idp, :pzaxcja, :producto_id ])
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@producto.productosxpza.build` deberías usarlo sólo cuando tengas una relación `has_many`.
En tu caso que es `has_one`, deberías usar `@producto.build_productosxpza`

Comment: Excelente muchísimas gracias, siempre aportando excelentes respuestas, oye pero aun no entiendo muy bien porque se usa uno en has_many y invierte en has_one ¿a que  se debe?

Comment: @Ing.LuisC en general al llamar a una relación `has_many`, independiente de si tenga o no elementos asociados, siempre va a retornar un objeto `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy` en el cual puedes llamar al  método `.build`. Ahora si llamas a una relación `has_one` o `belongs_to` que no tenga un elemento asociado, va a retornar `nil`, y como `NilClass` obviamente no va a tener el método `build`, lo que hace ActiveRecord es crear métodos dinámicamente para todos los `has_one` y `belongs_to` en el objeto padre, en tu caso, el modelo `Producto`.

Comment: excelente muchísimas gracias, me funciono bastante bien, pero tengo una duda: el formulario de crear y el de editar lo tengo en una misma acción que es la de index debido a que estoy aplicando ajax con este video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Il7PPhen3o mi problema esta en que en el formulario de editar no me esta tomando el metodo @producto.build_productosxpza debido a que el formulario esta se esta usando de esta forma: <%= form_for(producto, :method => :put, remote: true}) do |f| %> sin el @ en producto a diferencia del formulario create que si esta tomando el metodo

Comment: ¿como podría resolver esto?

Comment: @LuisCR Te sugeriría que si tienes otra duda, hagas una nueva pregunta. Esto por un tema de orden, ya que el código será mas legible a de lo que sale en un comentario, por si alguien a futuro tiene tu misma duda y le será más fácil encontrar la misma consulta a que en un comentario y por último para que otros usuarios eventualmente puedan responder tu pregunta y no solo yo (aunque la verdad no hay mucho apoyo en el área ruby, pero no se pierde las esperanzas). Saludos